# Show that a linear map $f=\lambda Id$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be finite dim  $K-$vector space. If w.r.t. any basis of $V$, the matrix of $f$ is a diagonal matrix, then I need to show that $f=\lambda Id$ for some $\lambda\in K$.

I am trying a simple approach: to show that $(f-\lambda Id)(e_i)=0$ where $(e_1,...,e_2)$ is a basis of $V$. Let the diagonal matrix be given by $diag(\lambda_1,...,\lambda_2).$ Then $$(f-\lambda Id)(e_i)=diag(\lambda_1,...,\lambda_2) (0,0,..,0,1,0,...,0)^T - (0,0,..,0,\lambda ,0,...,0)$$ $$=(0,0,...,0,\lambda_i - \lambda,0,...,0)$$ where $1,\lambda,\lambda_i-\lambda$ are in the $i^{th}$ position. I don't see how to conclude $\lambda_i=\lambda$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\lambda_i\ne\lambda_j,$ then $\{e_1,\cdots,e_i+e_j,\cdots,e_j,\cdots,e_n\}$ is also a basis for $V,$ where $e_i+e_j$ replaces $e_i.$ And, with respect to this basis, the matrix of $f$ is $(a_{ij}),$ with $a_{kk}=\lambda_k, \forall k,$ and $a_{ij}=\lambda_j-\lambda_i\ne0.$ But this contradicts the hypothesis that the matrix of $f$ with respect to any basis is diagonal, and hence $\lambda_i=\lambda_j:=\lambda, \forall i, j.$ This shows that $f=\lambda Id.$
Your approach missed the strong condition that the matrix of $f$ with respect to **any** basis is diagonal.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

$\def\\#1{{\bf#1}}$**Hint**.  If the matrix with respect to a basis $B=\{\\v_1,\ldots,\\v_n\}$ is ${\rm diag}(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n)$ then we have
$$f(\\v_1)=\lambda_1\\v_1\ .$$
Now apply this to three choices of basis: one where $\\v_1=\\e_1$, one where $\\v_1=\\e_k$ and one where $\\v_1=\\e_1-\\e_k$.